# Composer error while upgrading from Craft CMS 3.5.8 to 3.7.21

Tags: composer

I am trying to upgrade to the Craft CMS from 3.5.8 to 3.7.21. I am getting the below error. Any help really helpful.

Output:

```
<warning>Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
<warning>Package "yiisoft/yii2-shell" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.</warning>
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/homestead could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package laravel/homestead could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
<warning>Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.</warning>
```

```json
{
    "require": {
        "aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe": "3.0.3",
        "craftcms/aws-s3": "1.2.11",
        "craftcms/cms": "3.5.8",
        "craftcms/contact-form": "2.2.7",
        "craftcms/redactor": "2.7.4",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "modules\\": "modules/"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "laravel/homestead": "^7.20"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `composer.json`, looks like a misconfiguration.

Comment: @MoritzLost Ok adding the file below

Answer (score 1):

Your `composer.json` indicates that the `laravel/homestead` package couldn't be found. This is strange, as the package [does exist](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/homestead), even though you're requiring a heavily outdated version. Anyway, you can try requiring a current version of the dependency to see if that fixes it:

```
composer require --update-with-all-dependencies laravel/homestead:^12.0
```

Another option would be to remove that dependency altogether, as it doesn't look like you need it anymore and you can still install Homestead on your local development machine.

Comment: This fixed the issue composer remove laravel/homestead
for development Instance